# How can I improve this click/toggle function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, refactoring, click, toggle

```
$('.tabs a ').click(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    if (a == '#tab-1') {
        $('.btn-buy').hide();
        $('.btn-sell').show();
    } else {
        $('.btn-sell').hide();
        $('.btn-buy').show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

... it works, but the code is ugly, too many lines. Can it be reduced any further?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: As long as it works.... I have seen worse ;)

Comment: The code looks pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use toggle:

```
$(".tabs a").click(function() {
    $(".btn-buy").toggle();
    $(".btn-sell").toggle();
});
```

This would assume they start out in their correct state initially...

Comment: But this is not the same behaviour. If I understood correctly, it should only show the `buy` button if `#tab1` is clicked. This always toggles the state. So if I click on `tab2` twice or once on `tab2` and then `tab3`, the  button shows again.

Comment: There're only two tabs, so this works perfectly. But I just noticed IE doesn't show the btn-sell, hmm...

Comment: @Felix Kling: yeah, you're right actually... oh well, looks like the original code is the only way to get the desired behaviour :)